# Shifter won't click and cable doesn't move

Tags: shifter, cable, derailleur-front

My front gear is set on the smallest gear then the shifter suddenly doesn't click. I also see no cable movement from the front derailleur.

Here is the link for the vid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOlms.jpg
[image: Shifter]

[image]

Comment: Which way/direction do you click? What kind of shifter? What kind of derailleur? Is the cable tight or loose? How does the shifter look like?

Comment: the shifter is Ltwoo A2 - 3 speed, the cable is tight and the derailleur is stock from trinx.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  Some more information would be helpful.  Is the shifter completely frozen, or does it move but not click and without cable movement?  If you put your finger on the cable, do you feel it tensioning as you move the shifter?  Can you move the derailleur by hand, or is it locked in place?  The problem can, in broadest terms, be 1)  The thing doing the moving (the shifter), 2) the thing being moved (the derailleur) or 3) the thing transmitting the force (the cable).  Also, if you have a minute, pictures/videos are helpful in assessing the problem.

Comment: I've added images and vid on my post, there's no movement from the cable, I'm not sure with moving the derailleur because it might break. There's a click sound on high lever(the long one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a very simple issue - the cable broke. Possibly the head of the cable detached so that the shifter cannot grab the cable. There is a remote possibility the shifter itself broke where it holds the cable.

You can verify this by detaching the cable from the derailleur, you may find that end of the cable is loose and can be pulled out of the housing. Find a manual for your particular shifters and find out how to remove the cable. You may need to remove a cover to get access.

Yo should also verify the derailleur can move by pulling the cage carefully outwards - it takes a bit of force. The derailleur is robust enough that you will not break it.

The likely reason the shifter is not clicking is that it relies on the derailleur spring pulling on the cable for tension, so the internal parts are not moving when you work the thumb and finger levers.